# Dictionaries data in React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

I'm trying to design data flow in my React application. Do you have any hints how to manage dictionaries data? I fetch data sets from REST API like "Countries", "Currencies" and many other key-value pairs. These data can change in time but quite rare. I would like to store them somewhere on the client side, because fetching it many times will impact application performance.

Do you have any suggestions how to manage it? When fetch dictionary data, where store it and how to synchronize changes from server?

Answer (score 1):

Man your question can be broke into many questions, to make easy for you I'll give you the sources to look:

1)Store your data in your application
  react-redux.
2)Javascript dictionaries
  the concept exists as associative arrays like: object['name'] = value
3) to sycn your server with your application use axios.

cheers

Comment: I know it's a complex problem. I would like to follow good practices and use right tools.

Answer (score 1):

The most straight forward way, without running to redux / mobx etc, would be to request the data from a component as high in the component tree as possibe, e.g. `App` or similar, and provide the data to all children components through the `Context` API - https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

The most straight forward way to synchronize your data is already taken care of, as it would fetch new data if you were to refresh your screen or load the app from scratch again.  Otherwise you could `poll` with a timeout set by you, or more advanced, you could use websockets or something like a `subscription` from `GraphQL`

Comment: Fetch data when application is requested by user? I mean root element is rendered/page is refreshed. Is it good idea to store data in localStorage manually (as a serialized json)? I'm React newbie :)

Comment: You wouldnt need to use `localStorage` if you are just going to store the data in the root elements `state` and pass down via props, or else use the context API as mentioned above

Comment: It requires data fech each time user opens application/refresh page. It's ok for small dataset.